# how this for loop determines when to break the loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have encountered a different type of for loop which i don't see or use commonly.I tried to figure it out but get even more confused in the process.It doesn't have its third argument or even a check method to break the loop.Here it iterates over an array and prints its value.Actually it encounters 'undefined' value for a certain index but i am not telling it to break when it will encounter undefined.please help me to break the puzzle here...

```js
(function () {
    var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
    for (var i = 0, value; value = a[i++];) {
        document.write(value + '</br>');
    }
})();
```

Comment: `value=a[i++]` i is incrementing, condition for the loop is up to the last index `i` where `a[i]` is defined.

Comment: `for` loop is executed untill the value of the "condition part" evaluates falsy.

Comment: It's because the condition `value = a[i++]` is checked on each iteration. And when checking it `i++` increments `i`. when `i` gets too large, outside the array, i makes it `undefined`, which evaluates to false. But don't ever do a loop like this, it's very poor programming.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Actually this might be an efficient way to iterate through a loose array, when the aim is in stopping at the first `undefined` value.

Comment: @Teemu Readability is more important than micro-efficiency. Your right, but that wasn't the goal of that loop.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek the article where i encountered this kind of encouraged to use this method   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript

Comment: @user3138436 Well, that seems to be one of those MDN pages which "needs technical review". I mean just after your example they introduce `for..in` as an alternative method to iterate an array ... `for..in` is _definitely not purposed_ to iterate an array.

Comment: @user3138436 For learning purposes it's fine. It's simply focused on that you don't need to use `.length` when you iterate through the array. It's OK for JavaScript only for looking for a undefined index. But in any other language, this is going to give you a `index out-of-bounds` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript, when you access array elements beyond the length of the array, you don't get a range check error, the returned value is `undefined` which corresponds to `false` when treated as boolean - thus the loop termination when the end of the array is reached.

If any of the array elements is `undefined` or any other value that becomes `false` as boolean, the loop will terminate on that element.

The assignment operator in javascript returns a value of the left side, so expression `value = a[i++]` is used to return the value of `a[i]` and increment `i` - in that order. If this value converts to `false` as boolean, the loop is terminated.

Answer (score 2):

All arguments to for loops are optional.

The first statement in a for loop is just a variable declaration, as such you are allowed to define multiple variables. The author could've instead written:

```
var a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var value;

for(var i = 0; value = a[i++];)
```

but went for brevity instead.

The third statement (increment/decrement) is optional, the author (again going for absolute brevity) decided to use postfix increment (`i++` will return i THEN increment it, whereas `++i` will increment THEN return the incremented value).

They also could've written this:

```
(function () {
    var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
    var value;
    var i = 0;
    for ( ; value = a[i++]; ) {
        document.write(value + '</br>');
    }
})();
```

Finally, `a[a.length+1]` which would be the final condition evaluated returns `undefined`, which is a falsy value and will cause the loop to terminate.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things to note:

1. `undefined` is a "falsy" (not-true) value
2. A loop terminates when its condition becomes non-true
3. Assigning `a[i]` (or `a[i++]`) to `value` returns `value`

So, when `i == 9`, `a[i++] == undefined`, so `value == undefined`, so the loop terminates.

Answer (score 1):

For loop repeats until condition after the first `;` is true. In your case eventually after the last element in the array `a[i++]` will become falsy (`ToBoolean(undefined)`). Once it happens loop stops.

Take a look at specification for [For Statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.3):

> 3. Repeat
>          a. If the first Expression is present, then
>               i. Let testExprRef be the result of evaluating the first Expression.
>              ii. If ToBoolean(GetValue(testExprRef)) is **false**, return (normal, V, empty).

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0, value; value = a[i++];) {
```

the second part of for is evaluated as a condition for each iteration.

automatic type conversion happens here so that the value of `a[i++]` is evaluated. if `a[i++]` is true the loop continues, if not it stops.